# How to import Google Sheets Data to MongoDB Atlas Realm

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-apps-script, google-sheets, mongodb-realm

I am trying to import the data I have from my Google sheets doc to MongoDB Atlas. I have written the app script as well as the function in the function editor. When I run my code in the function editor in MongoDB I get this ERROR "mongodb insert: argument must be an object". Here is what I have so far:

Google Sheet APP Script

```js
function exportSheetsToMongo () {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("US");
  var headersRows = 1;
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numsRows = range.getNumRows;
  var data = range.getValues(); 

  for (var i = headersRows; i < numsRows; i++) {
    var usZipIdCell = range.getCell( i +1, columns.zip+1) // Error possible here
    // var description = data[i][columns.description];
    
    var formData = {
      // 'country': data[i][columns.description],
      'zip': data[i][columns.zip],
      'city': data[i][columns.city],
      'state': data[i][columns.state],
      'state_code': data[i][columns.state_code],
      'county': data[i][columns.county],
      'county_code': data[i][columns.county_code],
      'lattitude': data[i][columns.lattitude],
      'longitude': data[i][columns.longitude],
      'accuracy': data[i][columns.accurcay]

    };
    var options = {
      'method':'post',
      'payload': formData
    };
    if(description) {
      var insertID  = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://us-east-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/mmc-backend-mzbhi/endpoint", options);
      usZipIdCell.setValue(insertID)
    }
  } 
}
```

MongoDB Realm Function Editor

```js
exports = async function(payload) {
  
  const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
  const eventsdb = mongodb.db("us_zip");
  const eventscoll = eventsdb.collection("zip");
  const result = await eventscoll.insertOne(payload.query);
  var id = result.insertedId.toString();
  if(result) {
    return JSON.stringify(id,false,false);
  }
  return {text: 'Error saving'}
};
```

Partial Google Sheet Data

[image]

Data Base

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand the relationship between "Google Sheet APP Script" and "MongoDB Realm Function Editor". Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: The Google Sheets App script is a function on how to import the data and the MongoDB Realm Function is to insert that data in JSON format. I hope this helps, sorry I am new using the google app script and the mongo realm. I was trying to follow this tutorial https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/stitching-sheets-using-mongodb-stitch-to-create-an-api-for-data-in-google-sheets but it looks like 3rd party services have been depreciated.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your current issue, "Google Sheet APP Script" works fine. But "MongoDB Realm Function Editor" dowsn't work as you expected. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be with the data. You need to stringify it and set the application type. You are also accessing `payload.query` instead of `payload.body`. So something like this should work:

```js
    var formData = {
      ...
    };
    var options = {
      'contentType': 'application/json', // JSON application body type
      'method':'post',
      'payload': JSON.stringify(formData) // Stringify the data
    };
    if(description) {
      var insertID  = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://us-east-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/mmc-backend-mzbhi/endpoint", options);
      usZipIdCell.setValue(insertID)
    }
```

```js
exports = async function(payload) {
  
  const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
  const eventsdb = mongodb.db("us_zip");
  const eventscoll = eventsdb.collection("zip");

  const body = JSON.parse(payload.body.text()); // Parse the body of the 'request'

  const result = await eventscoll.insertOne(body);
  var id = result.insertedId.toString();
  if(result) {
    return JSON.stringify(id,false,false);
  }
  return {text: 'Error saving'}
};
```

I'd also recommend using `eventscoll.insertMany()` instead of `eventscoll.insertOne()` as this is going to make a url call for every entry in your sheet.